# Use free space after hiding axis

Tags: dimple.js

I have a horizontal bar chart where I decided to hide the Y axis and display the axis labels inside the chart:
[image]

Now I'd like to know how I can tell Dimple to use the free space (see red rectangle) available from hiding the Y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the bounds of the plot area with [setMargins](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#setMargins) or [setBounds](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#setBounds).  Dimple doesn't automatically size to accommodate axes. So just set the left margin to about 10px.